British 80s mini-TV series about impossible love triangle between Jewish boy, Muslim girl and white English girl
For years I have been trying to recall this mini TV series that definitely made an impact. I think I had a crush on the English girl in it. This is what I remember:

It was definitely English but it was also exported to Sweden, where I saw it.
Jewish boy falls in love with muslim girl and the English girl might possibly be in love with him. It was an impossible love-story. The muslim girl's parents did not approve, for example. Think Romeo & Juliet vibe.
About 3-5 episodes.
From the mid to late eighties I guess.
The boy was quite a looker, the muslim (Pakistani?) girl as well.
The white English girl wore a beret in some episode. 
The white English girl made love to the Jewish boy outdoors once.
There was probably a passage of time between episodes. I recall that the bloke came back from kibbutz in the beginning of one episode.   
Demographics: This was probably directed towards a youngish crowd. Maybe for 15-19 year olds.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.


It was an impossible love-story. The muslim girl's parents did not approve for example. Think Romeo & Juliet vibe.



There was probably a passage of time between episodes. I recall that the bloke came back from kibbutz in the beginning of one episode.



Demographics: This was probably directed towards a youngish crowd. Maybe for 15-19 year olds..



This was definitely English but it was also exported to Sweden, where I saw it.


Sounds like the British 5-part miniseries Shalom Salaam from 1989.

This miniseries is another high-quality BBC product with a clear social message. In it we see the dream of the multicultural society played out. The story evolves around two families, one Jewish and the other Indian Muslim, and follows a classical thesis - antithesis- synthesis pattern. At school the talented son of the Jewish family, owners of a textile works, meets the equally gifted daughter of the Muslim family, the mother of whom is an employee of the aforementioned textile enterprise.
The plot involves the deepening love between the two protagonists against a background of cultural differences, industrial conflict and social tensions.

The two young protagonists (Adam and Mumtaz) are pictured below (it's from a short online interview with the show's costume designer). And Clare Holman played Jackie, the Catholic girl that Adam was also attracted to.

